# How to show the Now Playing Tab in CarPlay?

Tags: ios, carplay

I'm working on an app that will support CarPlay.It's an audio app.

I'm able to show 2 tabs (favourite and recommended) though I just don't know how to show the Now Playing Tab. I just cannot find any info regarding this.
Do I have to manually show it, and the, how do I push? Do I have to do it manually? If so, what's the viewcontroller?

Thanks.

Comment: Pretty insane how inadequate the CarPlay documentation is!

Comment: WIth iOS 12, it got much better though.

Answer (score 3):

For the Transition to the *Now Playing* tab to work on both the simulator and an actual car, you need to make sure to

- call `beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents` on the current `UIApplication`, and
- set a `nowPlayingIdentifier` on the `MPPlayableContentManager`

before calling the completion handler in `playableContentManager:initiatePlaybackOfContentItemAtIndexPath:completionHandler:`.

Comment: Great! I've done the first and last suggestion and I think this has done the trick. I wonder if the second one is needed but I don't know how to do it. How do you set the now playing identifier?

Comment: @mike-nelson: `MPPlayableContentManager.sharedContentManager.nowPlayingIdentifiers = @[ nowPlaying ]`, where nowPlaying is the ID of the `MPContentItem` you have started to play.

Comment: Thanks @DrMickeyLauer, this works, it shows a little speaker icon next to the playing item in the carplay list view now. However, the `beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents` actually prevents now playing screen from showing unless I call `endReceivingRemoteControlEvents` and begin again every time play is invoked. This almost works perfectly, except the first time an item plays it refuses to show now playing screen. Any suggestion?

Comment: @DrMickeyLauer please can you help me, I have set things like this but it's not working: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64059229/how-to-make-nowplay-screen-in-carplay-xamarin-ios-and-how-to-set-nowplayingiden

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is a couple months old, but for me, I had to test in an actual device with CarPlay. Apple says always test it on an actual device with CarPlay. At first, I didn't see a Now Playing tab in the simulator, but as soon as it was tested in a device it was there automatically. I didn't do anything special. I think CarPlay knows when you're playing audio via MPNowPlayingInfoCenter and does this automatically in the actual CarPlay device.